# Fallback language mentioned in GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont file is not supported for a language

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, globalization

I am working on Globalizing my WPF application. We are supporting languages like Chinese and Japanese. I read online, if the font we mentioned in XAML is not supported by a particular language, WPF.Net framework uses fallback fonts from GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont file.

I was checking this file's contents. For Chinese language, they have Tahoma font as one of the fallback fonts. but Tahoma font doesnot support Chinese laguage. (as per this link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)

My question is- why do we have Tahoma as fallback font for Chinese if its not supported.

Comment: Because it's a fallback, not a catch all?

Comment: @Will, So you mean if it will not find suitable font, then it will fallback to Tahoma and might not show all the characters in chinese which are not supported by Tahoma ?

Comment: Your spare tire isn't the best tire on the car, it's something that will get you to the tire store when you are in desperate need. This is all speculation, but then this is all speculation anyhow, and my speculation is the best speculation. Prove me wrong.